# Alignment issue in election nomination editor toolbar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election

There is an alignment issue in the election nomination editor toolbar.

Initially I saw the alignment issue in the Puzzling and [post it on it's meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5110/21025). Today again I see the same issue in the [English Language Learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3143/28470). So I understand that the issue is not the community specific.

Hope same template is used for all the community's nomination page. So fixing on the template can avoid the alignment  issue in the future nomination pages.

**Update:** Recently found the alignment issue in [SO Election and reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337642/2451726)

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Nomination editor]

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: @Won't: The horror! The horror!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the editor toolbar alignment issue in the recent [Travel SE election](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) nomination page is fixed.

Lets wait for the moderator to confirm the alignment issue is fixed only for the Travel SE election template or all over the communities election template.

Screenshot for reference:

**Travel SE nomination page:**

[image: Alignment issue is solved]

**Update:** Verified in **Puzzling SE nomination page too.**

[image: Alignment issue is solved]